# Smack ejabberd connection error

Tags: ejabberd, smack

I am looking for a simple exmple to connect `ejabbered` using `smack` java client. Here is something i tried

```
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder builder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
    builder.setUsernameAndPassword("admin1@ejab", "123456");
    builder.setServiceName("ejab");
    builder.setHost("localhost");     
    builder.setPort(5280);

    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration build = builder.build();

       AbstractXMPPConnection conn1 = new XMPPTCPConnection(build);
       conn1.connect();
```

I am getting

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Used filter: No filter used or filter was 'null'
```

i am able to browse `http://localhost:5280/admin` . What is `servicename` & `host`. Can anyone give a simple example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to smack API, setServiceName parameter should be the domain of the XMPP service, so, in your case, it should be "ejab" (I suppose account "admin1@ejab" is correctly set in ejabberd). You can check with the section Hostname at ejabberd.cfg file.

e.g. from default ejabberd.cfg file

%% Hostname

{hosts, ["localhost"]}.

==> **localhost** is set as the service name

The setHost function parameter should be the server IP address or DNS resolvable server name. From your description that you access the ejabberd admin page using localhost, use the computer IP address that installed with ejabberd will be simpler.

Also, setPort should be the port that ejabberd listening at and its default is 5222 instead of 5280 (5280 is for administration through web). You can check with the listening ports from the ejabberd.cfg file to confirm.

e.g. from default ejabberd.cfg file

{listen,

[

{**5222**, ejabberd_c2s, [
.........

Below are the steps for adding a self signed certificate such that smack can work with. (Note : I use ubuntu server for following commands with openssl installed.)

1. create a certificate

   openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:1024 -days 3650 -keyout privkey.pem -out server.pem

   openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -out privkey.pem

   cat privkey.pem >> server.pem

   openssl rsa -in server.pem -out newcert.pem

   openssl x509 -in server.pem >>**newcert.pem**

   sudo cp newcert.pem **/etc/ejabberd/**
2. modify ejabberd.cfg to use the certificate

   {5222, ejabberd_c2s, [

   {access, c2s},

   {shaper, c2s_shaper},

   {max_stanza_size, 65536},

   starttls, {certfile, "**/etc/ejabberd/newcert.pem**"}

   ]},

   {s2s_use_starttls, true}.

   {s2s_certfile, "**/etc/ejabberd/newcert.pem**"}.
3. restart the service

   sudo service ejabberd restart

Comment: Now i am getting ` PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Comment: `builder.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);` fixed the issue of `PKIX path .....` and setting port to 5222 fixed the issue of smack connection

Comment: If you don't want to disable security, you may create a self signed certificate. It will give you more understanding before you put the server out to public and avoid those annoying exception.